# Express Gateway CORS + apiKey authorization 401 Unauthorized

Tags: cors, express-gateway

**Intention**

The CORS configuration seems to be valid and works, in a React-App I can easily access the gateway. Access via Postman is also possible, so the apiKey can't cause the problem.

But if I add authentication with apiKey, I get error messages in all browsers.
In Chrome:

**Issue**

> OPTIONS https://example-gateway.com/test 401
>   (Unauthorized)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://example-gateway.com/test' from origin
>   'https://example-app.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

What causes this behavior? Does the browser not send the required apiKey with the OPTIONS-CORS request and is therefore blocked?

How can this be solved?

**Code**

```
pipelines:
  adminAPI:
    apiEndpoints:
      - testApi
    policies:
      - cors:
          - action:
              origin: [https://example-gateway.com]
              methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
              preflightContinue: true
              optionsSuccessStatus: 204
              credentials: true
              maxAge: 600
              allowedHeaders:
                - Authorization
              exposedHeaders:
                - Authorization
      - key-auth:
          - action:
              apiKeyHeader: Authorization
              disableHeadersScheme: false
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: testBackend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `key-auth` is returning 401 for the `OPTION` call for CORS, which is the reason why probably you're receiving such problem.

Most likely you'll be able to resolve this by adding a condition on the key-auth call.

```
http:
  port: ${EG_HTTP_PORT:-8080}
# https:
#   port: 9999
#   tls: {}
admin: # remove this section to disable admin API
  port: 9876
  host: localhost # use 0.0.0.0 to listen on all IPv4 interfaces
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: '*'
serviceEndpoints:
  backend:
    url: 'http://localhost:9876' # btw this is EG admin API
policies:
  - proxy
  - key-auth
  - cors
pipelines:
  adminAPI:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
      - cors:
      - key-auth:
        - condition:
            name: not
            condition:
              name: method
              methods:
                - OPTIONS
        action:
          apiKeyHeader: Authorization
          disableHeadersScheme: false
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: backend
```

Comment: Can you please have a look? Another tip would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the example. 
I copied it but still get the error.
Have you tested it successfully and are you sure that it works like this?

Comment: I did! Are you still facing the issue? That's weird.

Comment: Okay so then I guess most likely I have some indentation mistakes in my yaml file, even though in the logs are no errors.
I will have a look, thank you.

Comment: Now it works! It was as suspected an indentation error. 

As a suggestion to make Express Gateway easier to use: 
a) Include this example in the documentation, I think this is a common use case 
b) EG should output errors in the logs if the config doesn't work completely

In any case: Thanks for your help and keep up the good work!